# to select all records from the last month but restricted records in the current month

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck to a problem in which I want to get all records from the previous month and to restrict the no of records in the current month,

For example I am fetching the reviews from the table, I have select a plan(according to app) if I select the plan starter only 80 reviews per month will be fetch in  the current month (you can assume less reviews for testing) or if the perfomance 250 reviews per month, so what I want to restrict the reviews with the current month with the previous records to fetch,

```
$sql_reviews_checksql = "SELECT count(*) as `count_review_monthwise` FROM `tbl_reviews_detail` WHERE MONTH(`review_posted_date`)='$current_month'";
      $rs_reviews_limit=mysql_query($sql_reviews_checksql);  
      $rows_from_review_tbl = mysql_num_rows($rs_reviews_limit);
      $row_fetch_count_month = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_reviews_limit);

      $count_review_monthwise = $row_fetch_count_month['count_review_monthwise'];
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query. It will get data from last month but not current month.

```
year(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(tbl_reviews_detail.create))) = year(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
and month(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(tbl_reviews_detail.create))) = month(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

or you can also try below one.

```
WHERE Your_Date_Column BETWEEN '2017-02-02' 
AND DATE_ADD(NOW( ), INTERVAL -1 MONTH )
```